# How to make javascript generated by `webpack output library` can be used in `nodejs` application

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am using `webpack` to package my javascript as a library. The library is used for two cases, one is inside browser and the other is to be used in nodejs application. Below is my webpack configuration:

```
output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
      path: outputPath,
      publicPath: '/',
      library: 'MyLib',
      libraryExport: "default" ,
      libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
```

For the browser case, users can reference it through html `<script>` tag like below:

```
<script src="https://myhost/mylib.js">
```

then the name `MyLib` is available in the glboal scope. I believe this is done by adding `MyLib` on the `window` object. 
The problem comes when I use my library in nodejs application. I will get `window is not defined` error. I think this is because webpack adds my library on `window` object which doesn't exist in nodejs environment. I wonder how I can solve this issue without breaking the browser users. Do I really need to release two version of `javascript`, one for browser and the other is for nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```
output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
      path: outputPath,
      publicPath: '/',
      library: 'MyLib',
      libraryExport: "default" ,
      libraryTarget: 'umd',
      globalObject: 'typeof self !== \'undefined\' ? self : this'
    },
```